# add an attribute at the end of the herf

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a menu with some herf like this to put some attribute at the end of the url after redirect

```
<ul>
<li><a href="/buzz#tab_pane_dashboard">By Keyword</a></li>
<li><a href="/buzz#table_profile_fbpage">By FB Page</a></li>
<li><a href="/buzz#tab_pane_fbevent">By FB Event</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then i tried to get the path value

```
  var path = window.location.pathname.split('#');
        var attribute = path[1];
        console.log(path);
<!----and do something!---->
```

But it returens an error :

> jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   .sa-tabs a[href=#tab_pane_dashboard]

so how may i solve it?

P.S: i am using easytab in somewhere else in my project.

Comment: Just use `window.location.hash` to get the hash.

Comment: thanks, i was going use this but am confused by the error message.

Comment: Where is the code that is selecting an element?

Answer (score 1):

You cant use any symbols in url , ? only usable,try.......

[By Keyword](/buzz?tab_pane_dashboard)

may work.

Answer (score 1):

```
  var x = location.hash;
    var valid = x;

    if(valid =="#test"){
     //do something
    }
    else{
     //else do something
    }
```

basically i used something like this to solve my problem